# Why isn't $p(x)$ identically zero in $F[x]/(p(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $F$ is a field and $p(x)\in F[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial. Then $K:=F(x)/(p(x))$ is a field extension of $F$.

I am confused: Why in this field $p$ has the root $x$, and why it isn't the case that $p$ is identically zero in this field?

Comment: Because $F$ is contained in $K$ and $p$ is not identically zero (it is in fact nowhere zero) in $F$

Comment: I think you mean $K:=F[x]/(p(x))$, not $F(x)/(p(x))$. $F(x)$ is the field generated by $F$ and $x$. Hence $F(x)$ is a field, so it has no ideals besides $(0)$ and $(1)$. So in $F(x)$, $(p(x))=(1)$, and $F(x)/(p(x))$ would be the trivial ring.

Comment: $\Bbb{C}=\Bbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ and $T^2+1$ has two roots, $x=i,-x=-i$ in this field

Comment: If $\,p(x) = x\,$ is identically zero on $\,F[x]/x\cong F\,$ then $\,1 = p(1) = 0,\,$ contra $F$ is a field.

Comment: It seems you may be confusing the "indeterminate" $X$ with $\,\bar x := x+(p(x))\in 
F[x]/(p(x)) =: \bar F.\,$ It is true that $\bar x\in\bar F\,$ is a root of $\,p(X)\in \bar F[X]\,$ but that doesn't mean all elements of $\bar F$ are roots. Indeed, since $\bar F$ is a field, $\,p(X)\,$ can have at most $\,\deg p\,$ roots. E.g if $\,p = x^2+1\,$ and $\,F = \Bbb R\,$ then $\,\bar F \cong  \Bbb  C\,$ and $\,i := \bar x\,$ is a root of $\,p(X) = X^2+1\in \Bbb C[X]\,$ but $\,p\,$  is not identically zero on $\,\Bbb C\,$ since its only roots are $\,X = \pm i.$ $\ \ \ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$p(x)$ is zero but the polynomial $p(T)$ in $(F[x]/(p(x)))[T]$ is not zero.

For example, let $p(T) = T^2 + 1$. Then in $\mathbf{Q}[x]/(p(x))$, the polynomial $p(T)$ splits as $p(T) = (T + x)(T - x)$. So $p(x) = 0$ but the polynomial is not identically zero.

If we write our polynomial ring as $F[x]$ then we want $x$ to be transcendental, meaning it is not the solution of any polynomial equation. Then in $F[x]$, two polynomials are equal if and only if they have the same coefficients—which would not be true if $p(x) = 0$. If we introduce a new relation: $p(x) \equiv 0$, then we can no longer use $x$ as the indeterminate of our polynomial ring. If $K = F[x]/(p(x))$ then $K[x] = K$, which is not the same as the polynomial ring $K[T]$.